# Spring Boot 3 Micrometer Integration with RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-resttemplate

I have upgraded to **spring boot 3**. I am trying to instantiate metric binder with pool connection manager.

```java
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute());
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute() * config.getNoOfRoutes());
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
        .create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder(connectionManager, "my-pool").bindTo(registry);
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

The previously used package

```java
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
```

The upgraded package

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
```

This updated package is incompatible with PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder with issue:
'PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder(org.apache.http.pool.ConnPoolControl<org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute>, java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)' in 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.httpcomponents.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder' cannot be applied to '(org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager, java.lang.String)'

I tried to update to the old package

```java
org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
```

and resolve this, but this cause issue with HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

```java
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
```

as the packages are incompatible
'HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient)' in 'org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory' cannot be applied to '(org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)'

Need solution to resolve this or any alternative approach.

Answer (score 2):

Both Spring Framework 6 and Spring Boot 3 removed support for HttpComponents 4.x (see this [Spring Framework issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28925) and [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32461)).

If you'd like to keep the connection pool metrics in your application, I would suggest to [ask the Micrometer team](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/) if they would consider supporting the new version of httpcomponents. Given the latest changes in Micrometer, the HTTP client itself could ship its own, optional, [Observability instrumentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/observation) like most Spring projects do now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Micrometer 1.10.x has done it for httpclient5 but not released yet in 1.10.4 :(
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/httpcomponents/hc5/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder.java
Need to wait for next release maybe 1.10.5 will include that.

Comment: 1.10.5 also didn't include that... 1.11.0-M1 has it so 1.11.0 final release should have it I believe...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the latest `micrometer-core` dependency too and in there there's a new `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder` in `io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.httpcomponents.hc5` package.

Here are the compatible imports:

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.httpcomponents.hc5.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder;

...

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute());
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute() * config.getNoOfRoutes());
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
        .create().setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder(connectionManager, "my-pool").bindTo(registry);
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

Also you could use the connection manager builder when constructing the connection manager and `HttpClients` class to build the client:

```java
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.httpcomponents.hc5.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder;

...

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setMaxPerRoute(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute());
        .setMaxConnTotal(config.getMaxConnectionPerRoute() * config.getNoOfRoutes())
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerMetricsBinder(connectionManager, "my-pool")
        .bindTo(registry);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
```